# Same/Fix alpha even for overlapping areas in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha, ggforce

I would like to first draw a bunch of areas and then have the resulting overall area be displayed with the same single alpha value. So instead of this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(
  ~xmin, ~xmax, ~ymin, ~ymax,
     10,    30,    10,    30,
     20,    40,    20,    40,
     15,    35,    15,    25,
     10,    15,    35,    40
)

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = dat,
            aes(
              xmin = xmin,
              xmax = xmax,
              ymin = ymin,
              ymax = ymax
            ),
            alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

I would want to have this as my outcome:

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I feel like the answer to my question may be similar to the one in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57394946/control-alpha-blending-opacity-of-n-overlapping-areas) but I don't fully understand it and thus am not sure. Also note that I used `geom_rect()` for the reprex, but ultimately I want this to work for [`ggforce::geom_circle()`](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/geom_circle.html).

## EDIT 1

[Quinten's first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73120682/8830099), which points to `scale_alpha(range = ..., limits = ...)`, is unfortunately not answering my question, since it can apparently only result in non-transparent areas.

## EDIT 2

[Quinten's updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73120682/8830099) is a workaround I could accept for the reprex above. However, as I've mentioned above, too, I want this to work for [`ggforce::geom_circle()`](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/geom_circle.html). Unfortunately, I guess I have to be more specific now and create another reprex. (Sorry)

```r
library(ggforce)
#> Lade nötiges Paket: ggplot2

dat <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 1.3, 1.6),
  y = c(1, 1, 1),
  circle = c("yes", "yes", "no")
)

ggplot() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_circle(
    data = subset(dat, circle == "yes"),
    aes(x0 = x, y0 = y, r = 0.5, alpha = circle),
    fill = "grey",
    color = NA,
    show.legend = TRUE
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = dat,
    aes(x, y, color = circle)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("yes" = "blue", "no" = "red")
  ) +
  scale_alpha_manual(
    values = c("yes" = 0.25, "no" = 0)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ggblend**

I also saw `ggblend` few moments ago, but wasn't sure it would fix your problem, luckily it does! You can do two things:

1. You can change your Graphics in Rstudio to "Cairo" like this:

[image]

Code:

```
#remotes::install_github("mjskay/ggblend")
library(ggblend)
library(ggforce)

# reprex 1 ----------------------------------------------------------------
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(
  ~xmin, ~xmax, ~ymin, ~ymax,
  10,    30,    10,    30,
  20,    40,    20,    40,
  15,    35,    15,    25,
  10,    15,    35,    40
)

p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = dat,
            aes(
              xmin = xmin,
              xmax = xmax,
              ymin = ymin,
              ymax = ymax
            ),
            alpha = 0.3) %>% blend("source")

p1
```

[image]

```
# reprex 2 ----------------------------------------------------------------
dat <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 1.3, 1.6),
  y = c(1, 1, 1),
  circle = c("yes", "yes", "no")
)

p2 <- ggplot() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_circle(
    data = subset(dat, circle == "yes"),
    aes(x0 = x, y0 = y, r = 0.5, alpha = circle),
    fill = "grey",
    color = NA,
    show.legend = TRUE
  ) %>% blend("source") +
  geom_point(
    data = dat,
    aes(x, y, color = circle)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("yes" = "blue", "no" = "red")
  ) +
  scale_alpha_manual(
    values = c("yes" = 0.25, "no" = 0)
  )

p2
#ggsave(plot = p2, "p2.pdf", device = cairo_pdf)
```

[image]

2. You can save the object as a `png` with `type = "cairo"` like this:

```r
library(ggblend)
library(ggforce)

# reprex 1 ----------------------------------------------------------------
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(
  ~xmin, ~xmax, ~ymin, ~ymax,
  10,    30,    10,    30,
  20,    40,    20,    40,
  15,    35,    15,    25,
  10,    15,    35,    40
)

p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = dat,
            aes(
              xmin = xmin,
              xmax = xmax,
              ymin = ymin,
              ymax = ymax
            ),
            alpha = 0.3) %>% blend("source")
#> Warning: Your graphics device, "quartz_off_screen", reports that blend = "source" is not supported.
#>  - If the blending output IS NOT as expected (e.g. geoms are not being
#>    drawn), then you must switch to a graphics device that supports
#>    blending, like png(type = "cairo"), svg(), or cairo_pdf().
#>  - If the blending output IS as expected despite this warning, this is
#>    likely a bug *in the graphics device*. Unfortunately, several
#>    graphics do not correctly report their capabilities. You may wish to
#>    a report a bug to the authors of the graphics device. In the mean
#>    time, you can disable this warning via options(ggblend.check_blend =
#>    FALSE).
#>  - For more information, see the Supported Devices section of
#>    help('blend').

png(filename = "plot1.png", type = "cairo")
# Output in your own folder:

p1
dev.off()
```

[image]
2

```r
#ggsave(plot = p1, "p1.pdf", device = cairo_pdf)

# reprex 2 ----------------------------------------------------------------
dat <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 1.3, 1.6),
  y = c(1, 1, 1),
  circle = c("yes", "yes", "no")
)

p2 <- ggplot() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_circle(
    data = subset(dat, circle == "yes"),
    aes(x0 = x, y0 = y, r = 0.5, alpha = circle),
    fill = "grey",
    color = NA,
    show.legend = TRUE
  ) %>% blend("source") +
  geom_point(
    data = dat,
    aes(x, y, color = circle)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("yes" = "blue", "no" = "red")
  ) +
  scale_alpha_manual(
    values = c("yes" = 0.25, "no" = 0)
  )
#> Warning: Your graphics device, "quartz_off_screen", reports that blend = "source" is not supported.
#>  - If the blending output IS NOT as expected (e.g. geoms are not being
#>    drawn), then you must switch to a graphics device that supports
#>    blending, like png(type = "cairo"), svg(), or cairo_pdf().
#>  - If the blending output IS as expected despite this warning, this is
#>    likely a bug *in the graphics device*. Unfortunately, several
#>    graphics do not correctly report their capabilities. You may wish to
#>    a report a bug to the authors of the graphics device. In the mean
#>    time, you can disable this warning via options(ggblend.check_blend =
#>    FALSE).
#>  - For more information, see the Supported Devices section of
#>    help('blend').

png(filename = "plot2.png", type = "cairo")

# Output in your folder
p2
```

[image]

```r
dev.off()
#ggsave(plot = p2, "p2.pdf", device = cairo_pdf)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Update**

What you could do is take the UNION of the areas using `st_union` from the `sf` package so you get one area instead of overlapping areas like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

dat <- tribble(
  ~xmin, ~xmax, ~ymin, ~ymax,
  10,    30,    10,    30,
  20,    40,    20,    40,
  15,    35,    15,    25,
  10,    15,    35,    40
)

area1 <- dat %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  as_vector() %>%
  st_bbox() %>%
  st_as_sfc()

area2 <- dat %>%
  slice(2) %>%
  as_vector() %>%
  st_bbox() %>%
  st_as_sfc()

area3 <- dat %>%
  slice(3) %>%
  as_vector() %>%
  st_bbox() %>%
  st_as_sfc()

area4 <- dat %>%
  slice(4) %>%
  as_vector() %>%
  st_bbox() %>%
  st_as_sfc()

all_areas <- st_union(area1, area2) %>%
  st_union(area3) %>%
  st_union(area4)

ggplot(all_areas) +
  geom_sf(alpha = 0.5, fill = "grey", colour = "grey") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(all_areas) +
  geom_sf(alpha = 0.8, fill = "grey", colour = "grey") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**First answer**

Maybe you want this where you can use a `scale_alpha` with `range` and `limits` to keep the area in the same `alpha` like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(
  ~xmin, ~xmax, ~ymin, ~ymax,
  10,    30,    10,    30,
  20,    40,    20,    40,
  15,    35,    15,    25,
  10,    15,    35,    40
)

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = dat,
            aes(
              xmin = xmin,
              xmax = xmax,
              ymin = ymin,
              ymax = ymax,
              alpha = 0.5
            )) +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0, 1), limits = c(0, 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this approach can only make the entire area non-transparent (alpha = 1), but not make the entire area semi-transparent with the same alpha-value e.g. 0.5?

Comment: @PaulSchmidt, Yes you are right, so it is a bit tricky to keep the alpha 0.5. So this fixed to have one area.

Comment: @PaulSchmidt, I updated my answer. You could UNION the areas to get one area using `st_union` from the `sf` package. As you can see in the answer, the alpha is now the same and you can even change it.

Comment: this is indeed an answer I would accept for the reprex I have above. However, as you can see in my 2nd edit now, it is my fault that my reprex was not precise enough, as your solution would not translate (I think?) to when I want to ultimately use ggforce::geom_circle().

Answer (score 2):

With `sf` and `purrr`:

- Create a list of polygons (rectangles)
- Create a multipolygon as union of these rectangles
- Display the result with `geom_sf`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

dat <- tribble(
  ~xmin, ~xmax, ~ymin, ~ymax,
  10,    30,    10,    30,
  20,    40,    20,    40,
  15,    35,    15,    25,
  10,    15,    35,    40
)

sf_rectangle <- function(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax) {
  st_polygon(list(rbind(c(xmin, ymin), c(xmin, ymax), c(xmax, ymax), c(xmax, ymin), c(xmin, ymin))))
}

rect_union <- dat %>% purrr::pmap(sf_rectangle) %>%
                      purrr::reduce(st_union)


ggplot(rect_union) + geom_sf(alpha=.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I randomly stumbled upon [{ggblend}](https://mjskay.github.io/ggblend/) and its `blend()` function. Basically, I only need to add `%>% blend("source")` right after the `geom_` that would overlay the multiple semi-transparent areas and it does exactly what I was looking for.

However, it does come with the limitation that can be seen in the `Warning` of the reprex below, i.e. you cannot actually get a preview of the plot in RStudio and even exporting it to some file types may not be possible, since not all devices can handle this. However, exporting to pdf via `ggsave(..., device = cairo_pdf)` works fine and I am showing screenshots of it below.

Nevertheless, I will leave this question open until I either find a way to also export `.png` and `.svg` or somebody comes up with an alternative solution that works for both reprex 1 and reprex 2.

```r
# remotes::install_github("mjskay/ggblend")
library(ggblend)
library(ggforce)
library(tidyverse)


# reprex 1 ----------------------------------------------------------------
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(
  ~xmin, ~xmax, ~ymin, ~ymax,
  10,    30,    10,    30,
  20,    40,    20,    40,
  15,    35,    15,    25,
  10,    15,    35,    40
)

p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = dat,
            aes(
              xmin = xmin,
              xmax = xmax,
              ymin = ymin,
              ymax = ymax
            ),
            alpha = 0.3) %>% blend("source")
#> Warning: Your graphics device, "png", reports that blend = "source" is not supported.
#>  - If the blending output IS NOT as expected (e.g. geoms are not being
#>    drawn), then you must switch to a graphics device that supports
#>    blending, like png(type = "cairo"), svg(), or cairo_pdf().
#>  - If the blending output IS as expected despite this warning, this is
#>    likely a bug *in the graphics device*. Unfortunately, several
#>    graphics do not correctly report their capabilities. You may wish to
#>    a report a bug to the authors of the graphics device. In the mean
#>    time, you can disable this warning via options(ggblend.check_blend =
#>    FALSE).
#>  - For more information, see the Supported Devices section of
#>    help('blend').

ggsave(plot = p1, "p1.pdf", device = cairo_pdf)
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
```

[image]

```r
# reprex 2 ----------------------------------------------------------------
dat <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 1.3, 1.6),
  y = c(1, 1, 1),
  circle = c("yes", "yes", "no")
)

p2 <- ggplot() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_circle(
    data = subset(dat, circle == "yes"),
    aes(x0 = x, y0 = y, r = 0.5, alpha = circle),
    fill = "grey",
    color = NA,
    show.legend = TRUE
  ) %>% blend("source") +
  geom_point(
    data = dat,
    aes(x, y, color = circle)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("yes" = "blue", "no" = "red")
  ) +
  scale_alpha_manual(
    values = c("yes" = 0.25, "no" = 0)
  )
#> Warning: Your graphics device, "png", reports that blend = "source" is not supported.
#>  - If the blending output IS NOT as expected (e.g. geoms are not being
#>    drawn), then you must switch to a graphics device that supports
#>    blending, like png(type = "cairo"), svg(), or cairo_pdf().
#>  - If the blending output IS as expected despite this warning, this is
#>    likely a bug *in the graphics device*. Unfortunately, several
#>    graphics do not correctly report their capabilities. You may wish to
#>    a report a bug to the authors of the graphics device. In the mean
#>    time, you can disable this warning via options(ggblend.check_blend =
#>    FALSE).
#>  - For more information, see the Supported Devices section of
#>    help('blend').

ggsave(plot = p2, "p2.pdf", device = cairo_pdf)
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Great you find your solution. I also saw `ggblend` package and wasn't sure if it would fit your problem. I added some code to my answer to save the output as png. You can use `png` with `type = "cairo"`.